# How can I (Should I?) modify the Eclipse build process to build a custom android build?

Tags: android, eclipse

I am working on a Java application that will run on an embedded system - a custom android build or modified AOSP. It is built on a linux server.

I would love to use an IDE like Eclipse with all its goodies like code completion, source code checking etc. but it seems very complicated. I looked at [Puri's blog here](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/)

for one, the build process of our custom android uses Android.mk makefiles.

How can I (Should I?) modify the Eclipse build process to build the custom android build?

Comment: Can you be much clearer about what you are doing?  Are you modding AOSP yourself?  Are you building an Android app that will run on a modded AOSP?  You can, certainly, do both of those with eclipse.  Please say more.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike I did not know the term 'modding' - had to google it :) Yes, our custom build is modifying AOSP.

Comment: Right!  In that case, I'll be you are building a custom pre-installed app.  See the answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can use either eclipse or studio to maintain a custom, pre-installed application.

In either case, you will **not** use the IDE to build the actual application image.  That will be built as part of the `make` from the root of the AOSP install(1)

You can, however, create a project whose root is the directory in either /device or /package that contains your app.

Once you've done that, read the Android.mk file to find dependencies.  Add them to the project as you would for any other project, for your chosen IDE.

If you go for eclipse, I suggest that you put the build directory somewhere in /out, or outside the AOSP directory altogether.  If the root make file finds it, it can be a problem.

When you need to test your app on a device or an emulator, use `mm` to build only your app.

Better yet, if possible, do most of the development for your app as you would any stand-alone app, so that you can easily install and test it.  Only put it in the AOSP directory as part of the release process.

1. Note, you can use either eclipse or studio to kick off that system
   build.  In eclipse, use External Tools.  Studio provides similar
   capabilities

Comment: the AOSP framework is modified and my app will be in it.

Comment: Yep.  Your build cycle will be much faster, though, if you can create a standalone version of the app, build and test it, and only install a releasable version in the AOSP root, for the ROM build

Comment: you mentioned, "I suggest that you put the build directory somewhere in /out, or outside the AOSP directory altogether". Is this the same as making what Puri's blog calls 'shadowroot' directory?

Comment: I tried (Import existing android code) but there were several project errors. a) what does one do with the gen directory? Also Eclipse generates files and folders like res - this could be bad. Trying New android project said R was not resolved... Note that in both cases, I specified build folder as external.